# Error 112 and Error 113 after adding foreign keys to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, foreign-keys

This is my table ( part of the whole thing , activity table still have other relationships with other tables) :

[image]

After adding foreign key and update my model EDMX from database in my visual studio , it came up this 2 error :

> Error 2   Error 112: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role
>   of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding
>   property types in the Principal Role. The type of property
>   'ActivityID' on entity 'istellarModel1.singalong' does not match the
>   type of property 'ActivityID' on entity 'istellarModel1.activity' in
>   the referential constraint
>   'FK_singalong_activity'.

and

> Error 1   Error 113: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'activity' in
>   relationship 'FK_singalong_activity'. Because all the properties in
>   the Dependent Role are nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role
>   must be '0..1'.

I checked my ActivityID in singalong have the same type as activity table's Activity ID , and i don't understand what error 113 actually means , i am new to database , at first i have many tables that don't link so i link them up after sometime and update my model ( EDMX )  in visual studio ( using entity framework ) and it gave me errors .

Any guidance on this please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `113` error sounds like your activity ID in `singalong` is NULLable.

It's stating that many-to-one is not valid if the dependent role is nullable.

That also seems to suggest the reason for the `112` - it's most likely complaining because it considers `NOT NULL` part of the type as well, so the two columns are different.

A quick fix may be to ensure that `singalong.ActivityID` is marked a `NOT NULL` but this will be problematic if you want singalong records with no corresponding activity.

I know how I'd fix it, at least initially, but it may be frowned upon be more knowledgeable DBAs: I'd simply add a dummy activity (eg, activity id = 0) to use for those cases where you would normally have NULL in the `singalong` table. I'm not suggesting you *do* that, but it's a possibility *I* would examine as a temporary fix, being far more of a pragmatist than dogmatist :-)

Comment: ActivityID in singalong is already marked NOT NULL , is there any other problem that lead to this? , and the error 113 talk about Principal role and 0..1 relationship .. making me confuse further.

Comment: @user2376998, no, not without seeing the actual table definitions in more detail. But you may want to check your comment. The phrase "Because all the properties in the Dependent Role are nullable" seems to disagree. Not saying you're wrong, just that it seems a little incongruous.

Comment: I have updated to include a screenshot of my table details , any more details u need ?

Comment: could it be the EDMX problem?

Comment: @user2376998: any more details? No. It looks like you are indeed correct which means this is beyond my area of expertise and you'll have to wait for someone else. I'll leave the answer here for informational purposes but I'll mark it CW since it's unlikely to be the eventual answer.

Comment: I believe I have the same issue as you. My DB column is NOT NULL but my class says it is NULL, and I'm getting error 113. So I dropped the constraint to try and at least get the class right first, and now it's just deleted all the autogenerated classes. I'm finding this a very painful slow bug ridden tool.

Comment: I got the class to update through trial and error. My class columns are still NULLable even though my database columns are not. This is really wasting a lot of my time.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question, but run into the same issue, and here is the fix.

If you open your .edmx file (using entity framework), you will see your different tables. If you click on the line linking the tables:

[image: tables]

It will show the properties. Select Multiplicity and set to 0..1
Your foreign key will need to be set as nullable.

[image]